# Full screen div after clicking image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Can I make a div appear at full screen after clicking a image? maybe with a nice fold open animation. I tried this without the animation:

HTML image:

```
<span class="image fit"><a href="#" target="_blank"><img src="images/image.png" alt="image" /></a></span>
```

HTML Div:

```
<div id="hidden">

</div>
```

CSS:

```
#hidden {
    z-index:9999;
    display:none;
    background-color:#fff;
    position:fixed;
    height:100%;
    width:auto;
}
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$( 'a' ).click( function() {
    $("#hidden").css("display","unset")
});
});
```

Comment: I assume your code opens a new tab and nothing else? What is the result you are getting with that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to replace `unset` to `block`, and add `preventDefault()` on click function.

Check updated snippet below..

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('a').click( function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      $("#hidden").show();
  });
  $('.close').click(function(){
      $("#hidden").hide();
  })
});
```

```css
#hidden {
    z-index:9999;
    display:none;
    background-color:#fff;
    position:fixed;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;    
    text-align: center;
}
.close {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    background: #000;
    color: #fff;
    cursor: pointer;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 30px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="image fit"><a href="#" target="_blank"><img src="images/image.png" alt="image" /></a></span>

<div id="hidden">
Full Screen Div
<div class="close">X</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! can I also add a close option once its open?

Comment: Perfect, thanks. Now I just need to find some animation so that it folds open

Answer (score 0):

You need to set `.css("display","block")` in your JS, when you click the element, and if you wanna have it filling up the entire width and height of the window, you could look into using `width: 100vw;` and `height: 100vh;` as this will take up the entire space available.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a simple animation. Use jquery's fadeIn() method.

```
$(document).ready(function({
    $( 'a' ).click( function() { 
       $("#hidden").fadeIn();
    }); 
});
```

You have to set your #hidden div's height and width to 100% and give it a fixed position.